# Using jQuery to filter data by quantity?

Tags: jquery, filter

I have a list of divs in an html page that look like this:

```
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="2">
```

It should be noted that not every div with the class product_listing has a quantity data value.  I want to fetch an array of every div with a data-quantity less than 20 and add a class called inventory_low to that product_listing div, so I wrote this in javascript.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var products = document.getElementsByClassName('product_listing');

var low_products = $(products).filter(function () {
    return $(this).data("quantity") <= 20;
});
$low_products.addClass("inventory_low");


});
```

The problem is that my filter function is not working, and I'm thinking that it's because not every product_listing has a data-quantity value.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Add a typeof check to $(this).data("quantity") and combine it with the other condition "<= 20".

Answer (score 0):

Try below code this is working code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //var products = $('.product_listing');
    /*----OR-----*/
    var products = document.getElementsByClassName('product_listing');
    var low_products = $(products).filter(function () {
        if ($(this).data("quantity") <= 20) {
            $(this).addClass("inventory_low");
        }
        //return $(this).data("quantity") <= 20;
    });
    //low_products.addClass("inventory_low");


});
```

```css
.inventory_low{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="2">2</div>
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="3">3</div>

<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="62">62</div>

<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="25">25</div>

<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="22">22</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$low_products.addClass("inventory_low");
 ^
This is not defined
```

Here is working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var products = document.getElementsByClassName('product_listing');
  var low_products = $(products).filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("quantity") <= 20;
  });
 
  /* You need correction here  */
  low_products.addClass("inventory_low");

});
```

```css
.inventory_low{
   background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="2">2</div>
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="21">21</div>
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="22">22</div>
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="9">9</div>
 <div class="product_listing" >Plain</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $(".product_listing").each(function(){
           if($(this).data("quantity")<= 20){
             $(this).addClass("inventory_low");
           }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See example below:

```js
var products = document.getElementsByClassName('product_listing');
$(products).each(function(index, object){
     if ($(object).data("quantity") <= 20) {
       $(object).addClass("inventory_low");
      }
});
```

```css
.inventory_low {
  background-color: #ffbdbd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="2">Product1</div>
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="21">Product2</div>
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="6">Product3</div>
<div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware">Product4 (no quantity data)</div>
```